# Apache cookbook fail to start

Tags: apache2, chef-infra, cookbook

I have followed the steps from Opscode Youtube video to create apache cookbook.

`~/chef-repo/cookbooks/apache/recipes/default.rb`

```
package "apache2" do  
 action :install 
end

service "apache2" do  
  action [:enable, :start] 
end

cookbook_file "/var/www/index.html" do  
  source "index.html"   
  mode "0644" 
end
```

but chef-client failed.

> Running handlers: [2014-10-31T10:58:27+08:00] ERROR: Running exception
>   handlers Running handlers complete [2014-10-31T10:58:27+08:00] ERROR:
>   Exception handlers complete [2014-10-31T10:58:27+08:00] FATAL:
>   Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-sta     cktrace.out Chef
>   Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.137832751 seconds
>   [2014-10-31T10:58:27+08:00] ERROR: service[apache2] (apache::default
>   line 14) ha     d an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed:
>   Expected process to exit with      [0], but received '1'
>   ---- Begin output of /etc/init.d/apache2 start ---- STDOUT: * Starting web server apache2 Action 'start' failed. The Apache error log may
>   have more information.    ...fail! STDERR: (98)Address already in use:
>   make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0     :80 no listening
>   sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs
>   ---- End output of /etc/init.d/apache2 start ---- Ran /etc/init.d/apache2 start returned 1 [2014-10-31T10:58:27+08:00]
>   FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef ru     n process
>   exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)

Comment: Not sure which OS you are using but if its rhel based this could be it? https://github.com/svanzoest-cookbooks/apache2/issues/342

Answer (score 1):

Something else is already listening on port 80 (`Address already in use`). You can use the command `sudo netstat -ltnp` to check what it is.

Comment: I'm not too sure whether I state correctly, I have execute the command and port 80 is to tcp(?)